# Why is std::dynamic_extent not zero in c++?

Tags: c++, standard-library, specialization

For context, I'm trying to make a span type that has a size type parameter, which mimics much of the std::span api.

`std::dynamic_extent` is not zero in C++, instead being defined as `-1ull` or `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`. when the `Extent` ntt parameter of a `std::span` is `std::dynamic_extent`, a `size` member variable of some description is created.  But when it isn't, the compile time value for the `Extent` parameter is used directly for the size instead.

I'm trying to understand why this decision was made, but more importantly, are there any tradeoffs with using 0 instead of max value here?

Comment: Who ever voted to close this as opinion based, care to share why tradeoffs are opinion based?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A known static size of zero is perfectly normal.

While manually deliberately writing it rarely happens (mostly for passing to other, generally generic, code), disallowing it would make generic code more unwieldy.
That's one of the problems with using raw arrays in generic code, aside from them not behaving like normal objects, and probably the main reason `std::array` is used there instead.

In contrast to zero, which as laid out already serves a necessary role, and in the absence of any negative values in search of meaning, the maximum value is the least needed, and in most cases memory and address space constraints mean it cannot actually occur anyway.